React: Button Requires Double Click to Trigger Email Sending After Data Load
I have a React component where I'm fetching data and attempting to send an email using the fetched data when a button is clicked. However, I'm encountering a problem where the button needs to be clicked twice for the email to send properly after the data has loaded.
const OrderCategoryList = () => {
  const { emailData,fetchOrderData } = useEmailData();
  const [orderData, setOrderData] = useState(null);
  const [userInfo, setUserInfo] = useRecoilState(userInfoAtom);
  const [orderID, setOrderID] = useRecoilState(takeOrderID);
  const setOrderIDType = useSetRecoilState(setOrderType);
  const setOrdername = useSetRecoilState(setOrderUsername);

  const handleOrder = async (id, status, username, orderType, email) => {
   setOrderID(id);
    setOrderIDType(orderType);
    setOrdername(username);

    await fetchOrderData();
    if (!emailData) {
      console.log("Email data could not be loaded.");
      return;
    }

    if (BOOSTER_STATUS === "order") {
      alert("You cannot take an another order.");
    } else {

        const templateParams = {
          // Assuming templateParams setup is correct
        };

        console.log('Template Params:', templateParams);
        await sendEmail(templateParams);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Failed to handle order:', error);
      }
    }
  };

  const sendEmail = async (templateParams) => {
    // Assuming email sending logic using emailjs is correctly set up
  };

  if (!orderData) {
    return (
      <Wrapper>
        <Container>No data available. Please relogin and try again.</Container>
      </Wrapper>
    );
  }

  return (
    <Wrapper>
      {orderData.map((item, index) => (
        <Container key={index}>
          {/* Render order items here */}
          <button onClick={() => handleOrder(item.id, item.status, item.user.username, item.orderType, item.user.email)}>
            Take Order
          </button>
        </Container>
      ))}
    </Wrapper>
  );
};

my customer useEmailData component
const useEmailData = () => {
  const takeOrderIDState = useRecoilValue(takeOrderID);
  const takeOrderType = useRecoilValue(setOrderType);

  const fetchOrderDataFn = async () => {
    if (takeOrderIDState === null) {
      return null;
    }

    switch (takeOrderType) {
      case "SOLO":
        return await auth
          .getSoloOrderId(takeOrderIDState)
          .then((res) => res.data);
      case "DUO":
        return await auth
          .getDuoOrderId(takeOrderIDState)
          .then((res) => res.data);
      case "NETWIN":
        return await auth
          .getNetWinsOrderId(takeOrderIDState)
          .then((res) => res.data);
      case "COACH":
        return await auth
          .getCoachOrderId(takeOrderIDState)
          .then((res) => res.data);
      default:
        return null;
    }
  };

  const {
    data: emailData,
    error: emailError,
    isLoading: dataLoading,
    refetch: refetchOrderData,
  } = useQuery({
    queryKey: ["emailData", takeOrderIDState],
    queryFn: fetchOrderDataFn,
    enabled: takeOrderIDState !== null,
  });

  return {
    emailData,
    emailError,
    dataLoading,
    fetchOrderData: refetchOrderData,
  };
};

export default useEmailData;

export const takeOrderID = atom({
  key: "takeOrderID",
  default: "",
});

export const setOrderType = atom({
  key: "setOrderType",
  default: "",
});

export const setOrderUsername = atom({
  key: "setOrderUsername",
  default: "",
});

I think it's most likely an async and sync problem. I've tried everything to fix this, but I still need to click twice for the email to send with the data.

I think you're right. I'm guessing that initially emailData is undefined or null. When you hit the button and the handler is called and fetchOrderData is called emailData is still undefined. When the data is received by the component the handler has no way of knowing that it's undefined until it gets called again. So you may want to rethink how that data is returned perhaps by using a mutation instead that will allow you to return data direct to the handler.

Unrelated to the issue but a suggestion. Why not condense the parameter to handleOrder so you only have to pass item then inside the function you can grab whatever property you want?

wow, it's working now! I added useMutation to useEmailData. Thank you so much! I need to study more about mutations now. :D

@hehehad https://tkdodo.eu/blog/mastering-mutations-in-react-query - the whole series of articles on his blog is very good.
